# Friend Referral Reward without Dynamic Links 2023 in Flutter / App development

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I so far implemented a friend referral system in my app allowing users to invite other contacts via whatsapp etc. - once the invite link is clicked the app is either installed or if already launched and the two users are connected as friends.
I built it using firebase dynamic links and flutter. Now that dynamic links will be shutting down I am looking for an alternative to cover this behaviour. So far I did not find a good one. I don't want to use 3rd party provider that complicate dependencies and increase costs.
Does anyone have experience how to implement this in 2023 ff.?

Cheers
timo

Answer (score 2):

The flow with the app already installed is easier and can be handled e.g. with uni_links https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links (not a service - just a wrapper over client libraries for App/Deep Links and Universal Links, on Android and iOS, respectively).

As for the flow that includes installing the app from the store...
On Android android_play_install_referrer can help with that (again, this is not a 3p service, just a client library for Android/Google Play functionality).
I'm not aware of a way to smoothly handle the flow without the app pre-installed on iOS; I believe that it was not possible since Apple changes a few years ago (unless you consider the clipboard workaround smooth, which I wouldn't). It's not totally hopeless, though - I found that it's reasonable to direct the user to a page that asks them to install the app from App Store (via a link) and then come back to click on another link on the same page acceptable UX.